# Problema al generar un controlador en Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net

Cuando deseo crear un nuevo controlador me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

Error al ejecutar el generador de códigos seleccionado: "El parámetro searchFolders no tiene entradas. Proporcione al menos una carpeta para buscar archivos. Nombre del parámetro: searchFolders"

[image: Imagen del error]

Intenté limpiar, compilar, recompilar la solución, cerrar Visual Studio 2022, reinstalarlo, repararlo y nada funciona, ya pedí a alguien Clonara el proyecto de Github y si puede crear controladores sin problema.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final encontré un video el cual indicaba que a la hora de instalar visual studio necesitaba tener algunas cosas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y cuál te faltaba? :)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es un video similar a este en el que se indica instalar todo salvo el "Windows Communication Foundation" tal y como se comenta:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kn3Aghypzcs